# Add small spaces around Bootstrap Grids (between the columns and rows)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have tried numerous approaches on this issue I have and cannot find the correct Bootstrap way. I am wanting to build a responsive simple website using the grids (or col) but with a gap in between each row and column (similar to what the FOLDY grid system does automatically for you). Snippet of my html code below along with screenshot of what it looks like on a webpage.

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 test">half</div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 test">half</div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 test">third</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 test">third</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 test">third</div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 test">10</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 test">2</div>
          </div>
        </div>

    .row{
  background-color: #eee; /* This changes colour of my background grid  */
}
```

[image: Picture of what the current code gives me with no gaps]

Links to Bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are applying a background to the row, so a gap between the columns will just show the row background.

But! If you set a background on the columns you may have the same issue, since bootstrap creates that gap using paddings on the columns https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#columns-and-gutters

What you can do is set a background on the column's child with the child using 100% of the available space.

EDIT: the code would be something like this https://jsfiddle.net/dnhv9x0p/

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row [class^='col-'] {
  padding: 3px 5px; // chenge the size of the gaps here
}

.row [class^='col-'] span { //i've used a span, but you can use any element inside columns, just make it a block
  background: #bbb;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi arieljuod, do you think you could help a little with the code/guidance, on your screenshot could I just alter the grid-columns class? Thanks so much, Kayleigh

Comment: @K.Haydock i've added a jsfiddle with the example

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I can't believe how long I've spent trying to figure this out!.... LIFE SAVER :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add a margin to the test class

```
.test{
    margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Matei, thank you that has added a small gap between the row however what about the columns?

Comment: Try adsing `padding:5px;` to the test class

Comment: Hi again Matei unfortunetely by replacing the margin with padding, it went back to no gaps whatsoever as you can see in my screenshot, and with adding both padding AND margin it still didn't add any gaps in between the columns. It's so fiddly I bet it's just one line of code I cannot find.

Comment: Well, is your css after the link to bootstrap?

Comment: Maybe add `display:block` to .test ?

Comment: I think the way to solve this would be to add inner divs to the cols, give them a class, and apply the padding to that class

Comment: Ok, I shall give that a go :-)